# Best technology to handle such a comlex system, Wep app + heavy processing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, drools

I'm working on a web application (JavaScript + PHP) for a taxi company. I need to add advanced alert system in which each app user (company employees) can specify what type of alert would like to get. Let' say user#1 wanted to track taxi#101 and get alerted whenever it enters any customer's district and show their details. user#2 wanted to get alerted whenever taxi#202 and taxi#303 enters any customer's area.. etc.

Note. There are many other cases for alerts but I prefer to think of theme one after the other.

I started scratching the high level design as follows:

> 1. I'll add an alert option to each taxi on the app.
> 2. user#1 will choose taxi#101 to get alerts from.
> 3. taxiID will be added to DB table with userID.
> 4. Do batch processing every 3 hours, joining this table with other table has taxi's positions.
> 5. Get a list of positions + area's + userIDs (not sure what technology should I  use here to generate this list).
> 6. Script to run and check each area from the list and get all customers info inside it.
> 7. Join result table from step 6 with table from step 3
> 8. Every time user logged in, scrip will run to check the table and list the customers info that the taxi comes near them.

My Questions are:

1. How can I translate these steps into real software design flow? (exact techniques)
2. There must be a technique to handle all this headache. imagine that there are 50 users and over 5000 taxi. I'm thinking of drools and started reading about it but still not sure how it fits here.

I'd be grateful for any hint.

**EDIT**

Thank you Alexander. Here are the answers for your questions:

```
Q: why would any one user even need to get alerted?
A: I'm not sure. For generating reports or something like that.

Q: Do you always know the positions of Taxis?
A: Yes, The system receives real time positions through GPS

Q: Do you always know the positions of Users?
A: No, it's not important. thy are regular employees. I just need their IDs so I can show each one the info he asked for.

Q: How do you know what an 'area' is, and what determines if a user/taxi is in range?
A: When I get the position of the taxi, I draw a virtual zone around it and call it and area. It should inserted in the DB as well.

Q: are the rules predefined? Or must the user be able to create them dynamically?
A: Yes, they are predefined. There are many other rules such as [The user can choose to get alerted when specified taxi has not moved for a long time]. but I started with this one.
```

The scenario, each user will request different alerts for different taxis and I should do some processing then display the results for each user.

I couldn't figure out  how to process these different variables and what's the best solution for this case.

Comment: 50 users.... this is what you call complex and heavy?

Comment: actually there are over 5000 users but I'll start with one department, plus they asked for over than 10 different types of alerts so it'll be quite heavy processing

Comment: Do i missunderstand something or wouldnt it be dificult to compare a table only updated every 3 hours with real time customer positioning ?

Comment: That's exactly true. I'm looking for other solutions but no luck so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Out of interest:** why would any one user even need to get alerted?

**What data do you have access to?**

Do you always know the positions of Taxis? Is this GPS? Do drivers add/update data?

Do you always know the positions of Users? Is this GPS? Do users add/update data?

How do you know what an 'area' is, and what determines if a user/taxi is in range?

**KISS - Keep It Simple Shadin**

I propose the following entities in your system:

```
Taxi
    + id : int
    + positions : Position[]

User
    + id : int
    + username / password / email etc
    + observing : Taxi[]
    + rules : Rule[]

Rule
    I do not know what you need or expect from this
```

I don't know what you mean by area, but you probably need some entity for that as well, though maybe not in the database - I don't know.

Now, for the rules. It seems you want a Domain Specific Language ([DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)).

Then the question becomes, are the rules predefined? Or must the user be able to create them dynamically?

If they are predefined, you could simply implement a class for that rule, and execute it in your controller (or whatever you use to handle http requests) when it's time to check that rule. Something like `myRule.checkFor(user)`. May even be a worker process of some kind.

**I'll update my answer when you answer my questions as comments :)**

EDIT:

Ok, so I think I'm starting to get a feel for your problem. This would be my solution:

**REST API:**

```
POST yoursite.com/v1/taxi/1.json {x:0.23, y:23} //update position for taxi 1 with json payload
POST yoursite.com/v1/user/1/register {taxi:1, eventType:NO_MOVEMENT, args:"3600"} //no mov for 1 hr
POST yoursite.com/v1/user/1/unregister {taxi:1, eventType:NO_MOVEMENT }
```

This seems to me should be sufficient for aggregating the data you need. It answers the following questions:

```
Where are the taxis? Which user is looking for events on x taxi?
```

You'll need a table (taxipos) for storing taxi id and it's position. [taxiid:int, long:float, lat:float]

You'll need a table (listeners) for storing which taxi is listened to by which users and for what event. [userid:int, taxiid:int, event:enum, arguments:string]

You'll need a table (events) that stores each event. [eventid:int, eventType:enum, taxiid:int]

The next step in my proposed solution would be to have a worker continuously aggregate events based on the recieved data. Say you define a NoMovement process. This process is run at a frequency that is sufficient to detect the least allowed interval in your system. For this example, lets assume that we could run at 15 minute interval (that is to say, you're not interested in a taxi that stands still for 14 minutes).

Now, each of your processes will be able to store events in a new table in your database. Let's investigate the NoMovement process (which will be run every 15 minutes by your worker):

```
For each $taxiid present in listeners@taxiid
  Retrieve taxipos closest to now, and taxipos closest to 15 minutes ago (interval must be => to 15 minutes)
  Check distance between now, and 15 minutes ago
  If distance is <1 THRESHOLD (I don't know what this should be) 
    Add to event table with (eventType:NO_MOVEMENT, taxiid: $taxiid) you'll get that from the loop
```

Finally, it's just a matter of

```
GET youriste.com/v1/events/taxiid (your client will need to store which taxiids we want to ask for events, and call get at an appropriate interval - your client should then locally set event by id as read and filter those out before alerting)
```

Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited my post and answers your questions. I'd like to know more about your suggestion please.

Comment: Updated post for you @Shadin

Comment: Can't thank you enough Alexander!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying, it sounds like your system will include mobile devices of some kind, and you will need a map system for tracking.

Best solution I can recommend is using something like Leaflet with the openstreetmap api,this would give the map as an svg with ample xml data for tracking locations, and a simple js script that would use ajax to post location data to the server at set intervals.

Using backbone js gives simple event listener control for your alerts. Just have to test taxi location vs customer area when locations are updated.

List of OSM frameworks including Leaflet http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks

Comment: I'm gonna look at that! thanks a lot